# Can I use Male mini DP to male DP on my monitor and get some results?

Tags: multiple-monitors, connection, displayport

I have a notebook that has mini DP port and i need to plug it into my DP monitor and I am not sure if I can use a cable that is mini DP male to DP male? This question might sound stupid but I really am not sure and dont want to waste money on something that would not work. And also I could not find anywhere if this combination of mini DP to DP (male to male) even possible and more importantly both sided.

Comment: What is the make and model of the notebook? Then we may be able to find out which version of DisplayPort it uses. However, DP version 1.2 supports up to 3840 x 2160 pixels at 60 Hz, so if you don't need more than that then a version 1.2 cable will work well enough.

Comment: I have acer predator helios 300 with intel i7-10870H, GeForce RTX3080 laptop GPU with 8gb VRAM and 16gb of RAM but if I remember correctly it might be custom in some way but only little bit. And my monitor is MSI optix G27CQ4 E2. Hope you can help me then :D!

Comment: @JakubKvapil that laptop is recent enough that you shouldn't have to worry about anything. Most of those dual graphics machines use the display output of the processor and [according to Intel](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/208018/intel-core-i710870h-processor-16m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz.html) that processor can do `Max Resolution (DP)‡ 4096 x 2304@60Hz` The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_DisplayPort) also states that the video output on Mini DP is `Video signal: Same as DisplayPort` and is just a miniaturised Displayport connector.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thank you very much! Now i do not have to worry about my order I just made! I would flag you as an answer too but I do not know how to do so :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mini-DP to "full" DP cable is exactly what you are expected to use.

Mini-DP is only really used where space is at a premium, generally on thin laptops, and I've never seen a monitor with a mini-DP connector. Mini-DP is purely just a miniature version of a DP connector.

You may have to look at your machine specifications to find out what version of DP is supported as it may limit you to 4K resolution at 30Hz if it is particularly old, but most should support 4K@60 at least.